# First meaningful paint shoots up from 300ms to 6700ms in development mode to production mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

I am writing a PWA and using lighthouse to audit my app. There is one point where I am sort of stuck. Here is the thing.
When I do a production build( I am using  for my 3 JS files( vendor, app and manifest ), the load time is surprisingly very high.
[image: page load performance in webpack production mode]

When I do the same for my webpack build in dev mode and audit the app, I get this
[image: page load performance in webpack dev mode]

This seems very very counter intuitive.

P.S. :I am using [webpack cache](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache) in dev mode 
and UglifyJsPlugin for uglify

Here is the webpack config

```
    var path = require('path');
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var ReplaceHashWebpackPlugin = require('replace-hash-webpack-plugin');
var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

var DEV = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
var BUILD_GLOBALS = {
    '__DEV__': DEV,
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development')
};


module.exports = {
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        build: './src/init'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.json', '.webpack.js', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                // loaders: DEV ? ['react-hot','babel-loader'] : ['babel-loader']
                loaders: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader!css-loader']
            }
        ],
        // preLoaders : [
        //  {
        //      test : /\.jsx?$/,
        //      exclude : /node_modules/,
        //      loaders : ['eslint-loader']
        //  }
        // ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist'], {
            root: process.cwd(),
            verbose: true
        }),
        new(webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin || webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin)(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(BUILD_GLOBALS),
        new ExtractTextPlugin("default.css"),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'vendor.bundle',
            minChunks: function(module) {
                // this assumes your vendor imports exist in the node_modules directory
                return module.context && module.context.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1;
            }
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: 'manifest'
        })
    ].concat(DEV ? [
        // new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
        new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
    ] : [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
    ]),
    devtool: DEV ? '#inline-source-map' : false,
    cache: DEV

};
```

Comment: Well you need to show us your webpack config

Comment: Did you put scripts at the end of your page or in your header? You may get better results if you make several bundles and use service worker (not supported in all browsers)

Comment: Yes, I have put the scripts at the end. Also, I am using service worker :)

Comment: I have added the webpack config for reference

Comment: If you look at the two version using Chrome DevTools, what's the cause of the different timings?